# How to go through Views without reload them again if I return back Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have ViewController1 and ViewController2 . When i click a button on the ViewController1 should go to ViewController2 and when press a custom back button should return to ViewController1 without reloading its content for ex:- if i type something on ViewController1's text filed it should remain as it is.
Does anyone knows any solution for this?

Comment: you want  ViewController2 parent and then dismiss so your text field data, not change

Comment: In vc1 viewWillDisappear store textField value somewhere (for example to NSUserDefaults), in viewDidAppear read it back and set to the textField.

Comment: @Eridana not the thing i want. I don't want to refresh the view when im coming back. I know what you are suggesting. It's not what i want.

Comment: @SaraMethuz actually im not clear about your solution. I think parent Vc should be VC1.

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan When you click the viewcontroller1 button you want to show the second View controller. At that movement, you want to present second View Controller. at that movement, you text field data as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> viewcontoller1 button click code...

```
@IBAction func Parsent(sender: AnyObject) {
    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier" as! ViewController2
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
    self.present(navigationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

> ViewController2 button code here..

```
@IBAction func Dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Load View Controller 1

2- Your custom button should present ViewController 2 on top of view controller 1 (the native self.present does this, note that it present it on top of VC1 so VC1 is still there)

3- your back button on View Controller 2 dismisses View Controller 2 and you return to View Controller 1 the same as you left it

Hope this helps!